# What is connection time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, monitoring

We are currently trialling [ManageEngine  SQLDBManager Plus](http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/sql/). On the dashboard for a server it shows connection time in milliseconds (currently 15ms).

Can anyone tell me what Connection Time represents and/or what I could use this metric for?

We are monitoring a MS SQL Server 2005 database if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the **help** section on their website](http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/sql/help/monitors/session-metrics.html), they describe *Connection Time* as the following:

> **Connection Time**: Displays the time taken to get connected to the SQL database server.

From that brief description, I'd be willing to say that it is the time duration between initiating the connection to the SQL Server instance.

If this is the case, then the impacts here would be the physical network latency and the server capabilities for a client response.  For further investigation into this metric, I'd consult the actual vendor for more details and acceptable statistics.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had read the manual but obviously missed it.

Comment: @Greg No problem, glad to help.  It definitely wasn't the easiest manual to sift through.